# PHP AND OR , Is this valid?

Tags: php

Is this valid?  I want to check if 'One' is not blank AND two is either blank or undefined. Can i use the brackets that way around both of GET[two]?

```
if( $_GET["one"] == '' &&  ($_GET["two"] == '' ||  $_GET["two"] == 'undefined') ) {
 // do X
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Oops. Looks like its a problem with my jquery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly valid. Basically, your if checks if BOTH cases (1) one == '' and (2) two == '' or two == 'undefined' exists. (2) evaluates as true if two is either '' or 'undefined'

The brackets are perfectly valid. :)

Comment: Thanks.  Its not working like i'm trying so maybe something else is causing the problem.

Comment: Try var_export-ing $_GET, and results of == comparisons, to see what's the problem. Oh, also, I've forgotten. If the _GET value is NOT passed in the URL (basically, if you're not expecting ?one=&two=) then you don't check against == '', you check with isset($_GET["one"]). Try it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. ?one=&two= does always show up in the url.  I'm going to use some of what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is valid. It should do exactly what you want.

If you need to check for empty strings or `NULL` values, you can also use the `empty()` function:

```
if (empty($_GET['one']))
```

Comment: apparently when variables are not set, PHP doesn't give "undefined"

Comment: @thephpdeveloper No, but that value could have come from a Javascript function, which could print `undefined`

Comment: @thephpdeveloper, no, if you want to check if variables are not set, you do a === check against null, or isset($variable). The OP is asking for a literal check against 'undefined', a string.

Comment: undefined is something thats returned in safari for some reason.  All other browsers just have blank

Comment: @thephpdeveloper there's nothing stopping anyone to do things like `<input value="undefined" />`

Comment: @andreas .. yeah its actually from an input box's custom attribute which is blank in all browsers other than safari.  I use the value to make a jquery ajax call.